# how can I display saved data when I restart Activity

Tags: android

In my Project I want to play audio files in mediaplayer and displays progressbar. If I exit the application then also player have to play audio file. If I restart The `Activity`
I have to display progress bar with last activity progress.

Here I tried using `onSaveInstanceState()` method. But I cant display progress bar with last progress. when I exit the activity player is playing but when I restart activity it stopped and displayed new view without any progress and saved data.

Answer (score 0):

A media player is the common example of use of an [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).
Your service should be in charge of playing the music and your `Activity` of showing the progress.